# How can I resolve CrashLoopBackOff error I keep getting after deployment in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I am deploying a frontend and backend application. The frontend is dependent on the backend for it to get data using the `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` variable whose value is the `IP:PORT` of the backend. But because I am using nginx to serve the application, the app wont work until `http` is added to the `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` value i.e `http:IP:PORT`.

This is the nginx.conf content

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /app/dist;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location = /index.html {
        expires -1;
    }

    location /proxy/ {
        proxy_pass $VUE_APP_PROXY_URL;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When I deploy using `dockercompose` on my local machine when setting `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` to `http://192.168.56.28:5000`, the application works perfectly.

Now I want to deploy to k8s, my backend deployment deploys without any issue but the frontend deploys but the pod is always on `CrashLoopBackOff`. I decided to dig into the issue, when I set `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` to `http://192.168.56.28:5000` in the deployment file, the pods deploy without the error, but the app will definitely not sync with the backend pods because `192.168.56.28:5000` is not the `IP:PORT` of the backend service.

These are my k8s files.

**Frontend.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  namespace: hostspace
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vue-application
        image: achebeh/community-challenge-frontend 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: VUE_APP_PROXY_URL
          value: "http://BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR:BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT_5000_TCP_PORT"
```

**Backend.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  namespace: hostspace
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-application
        image: achebeh/community-challenge-backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
        - name: CF_API_EMAIL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: hostspace-configmap
              key: cf_api_email
        - name: ZONE_ID
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: hostspace-configmap
              key: zone_id
        - name: CF_API_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: hostspace-secret
              key: cf_api_key
```

**frontend-service.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: hostspace

spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

**Backend-service.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
  namespace: hostspace
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

I have tried setting the `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` variable in the frontend-deployment.yaml file to both `backend-service`, `http://BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR:BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT_5000_TCP_PORT`, and `BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT_5000` but it just doesn't work. The pod keeps crashing. Please remember I added if I set `VUE_APP_PROXY_URL` to `http:192.168.56.28` the pod doesn't crash but it doesnt get data from the backend, please how can I resolve this.

Also I created the images myself, and when deployed locally it works.